# Elixir Phoenix Liveview Form Submission Problem With Disabling Submit Button

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

In a liveview, I have a form that is defined like this:

```
<.form let={f} for={:user} action={Routes.user_path(@socket, :create)} phx-change="validate_changeset" phx-debounce="blur", as={:user}>

...

</.form>
```

The submit button looks like this:

```
<%= submit "Save", phx_disable_with: "Saving...", disabled: {"#{!@trigger_variable_when_changeset_is_valid}"}%>.
```

All this is fine and dandy, but as soon as the trigger variable evaluates to true, all the fields in the form get cleared out and the button is disabled again. Can anyone explain this behavior and does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Can you add more context to the question? Maybe include the `validate_changeset ` function which I assume is where @trigger_variable_when_changeset_is_valid  changes and some of the input fields maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

This is my form

```
<.form for={@form} phx-submit="hello" phx-change="validate">
```

This is my button to send the form.

```
<.button :if={@form.source.valid?}>Send proposal</.button>
<.button :if={not @form.source.valid?} disabled class="cursor-not-allowed">
              Send proposal
            </.button>
```

This is my handle event function

```
def handle_event("validate", %{"hello" => contact_form}, socket) do
    changeset =
      %Hello{}
      |> Contact.change_hello(contact_form)
      |> Map.put(:action, :validate)

    socket = assign(socket, form: to_form(changeset))

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```